# Why this event not fired?

Tags: c#, events

I am practicing events but this code gives me error "Error  1   The name 'Productfinished' does not exist in the current context". I just want to fire the event and print the message but something is wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Event2_2
{
    class Product
    {
        public delegate void ProductFinishedEventHandler();
        public event ProductFinishedEventHandler Productfinished;        
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product pd = new Product();
            pd.Productfinished += new Product.ProductFinishedEventHandler(SendMail);
            Productfinished();
}
    }

    public static void SendMail()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mail sent to Vendor");
    }
}
```

Comment: Becouse you don't fire it anywhere.

Comment: The title of this question is wrong. Don't ask "why does the code behave like this" if the problem is a compiler error.

Comment: Productfinished();    isn't this firing the event?

Comment: This is telling to delegate - "Invoke all methods attached to it when event is fired."

Answer (score 1):

`Productfinished` is not a member of `Program`, it's a member of `Product`, that's why you're getting the error.

To raise the event you need to add a method to the `Product` class to fire the event. For example:

```
void OnProductFinished()
{
  var handler = ProductFinished();
  if(handler != null)
  {
    handler();
  }
}
```

Note that you need to check that there are handlers assigned to the event before firing it. It there aren't any then the event is null.

Also, it pays to follow the .Net event pattern. The easiest way to do this is to use the `EventHandler<>` delegate:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Productfinished;
```

And now to raise the event you say:

```
void OnProductFinished()
{
  var handler = ProductFinished();
  if(handler != null)
  {
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

You'd then declare you `SendMail` method as

```
public static void SendMail(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Mail sent to Vendor");
}
```

And you can easily attach the event handler by just saying:

```
pd.Productfinished += SendMail;
```

Comment: Also, if he's using the latest version of C#, he can just go `handler?.Invoke()` :)

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need to create your own delegate for an event. You can use the built-in `EventArgs` delegate, like so:

```
using System;

namespace Event2_2
{
    class Product
    {
        public void OnSendMail()
        {
            Productfinished?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Productfinished;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product pd = new Product();
            pd.Productfinished += SendMail;
            pd.OnSendMail();
        }

        public static void SendMail(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mail sent to Vendor");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to pass arguments to your event handler, create a class derived from `EventArgs` (the convention is that it has a name that ends in `EventArgs`) and use it to encapsulate the arguments.

Then declare the event as being of type `EventHandler<T>` where `T` is the name of the event args class you created.

For example:

```
using System;

namespace Event2_2
{
    public sealed class SendMailEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public SendMailEventArgs(string recipient)
        {
            Recipient = recipient;
        }

        public string Recipient { get; }
    }

    class Product
    {
        public void OnSendMail(string recipient)
        {
            Productfinished?.Invoke(this, new SendMailEventArgs(recipient));
        }

        public event EventHandler<SendMailEventArgs> Productfinished;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product pd = new Product();
            pd.Productfinished += SendMail;
            pd.OnSendMail("Test Recipient");
        }

        public static void SendMail(object sender, SendMailEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mail sent to recipient: " + eventArgs.Recipient);
        }
    }
}
```